# Overwriting an image button with another image when I click that button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created an image button (*a.png*) infront of each row in the *cellForRow* method. In the same method itself I'm calling a *buttonPressed* method which has the code to be executed when the button is pressed. And I want that on the pressing of the button, the button image should be changed to another image (*b.png*) of the same size.

Please help with how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
[but setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[but setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

try this......

Comment: UIImageView *i = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2,      20, 25)];
    i.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"user.jpg"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:i];

Comment: this would normally work...but I can't use cell in my function.

Comment: you want to change the cell of the table or what i am not getting u

Comment: no I just want to overwrite that image button with another image.

Comment: where are u adding that image button

Comment: UIButton *b=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,0,40,40); [b addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"a"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]

Comment: the above code is what I am writing in the cellForRow method ...The image button is placed to the right of the row.

Comment: Hakuna you should really read some books about programming patterns your questions show that you know barely nothing abouth that

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom Cell for UITableView and UIButton on Custom Cell.

Create property for UIButtion.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

```
//Set Action on  Button  in Table View Row

[cell.UIButtonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This will create action from your button.

And in method

```
-(void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{

NSSet *touches=[event allTouches];

  UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];

 CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.historyTableView];

//GET IndexPath

NSIndexPath *indexPath=[self.TableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];        

 selectedCell= [PairTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[selectedCell.UIButtonOutlet setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(12,12,200,200)];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(click: withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTag:indexPath.row];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

then in the click action method of button

```
    -(void)click:(UIButton *)button :withEvent:(UIEvent *)events{
       [self yourFunction:(UIButton *)button];

    }
```

then finally

```
   -(void)yourFunction:(UIButton *)button{
     button.selected = ! button.selected;

                if (button.selected) {
                    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
                else{
                    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                }

}
```

Comment: my click function is: 
-(void) click: (id) sender withEvent: (UIEvent*) event{
//here I am using sender.tag
and I am calling a third function from here where I want to change the image of that button
}

Comment: Pass the same UIButton as a input parameter in the third function and then apply the above code there

Answer (score -1):

Try this when initializing your button

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then modify your method(which is called when button is pressed) like this

```
-(void)yourMethod:(id)sender{

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //your other code

}
```

Comment: UIImageView *i = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2, 20, 25)]; i.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"user.jpg"]; [cell.contentView addSubview:i]

Comment: this would normally work...but I can't use cell in my function

Comment: UIButton *b=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,0,40,40);
[b addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"a"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: add this....   [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: you mean in the cellforRow method? 
coz I can't use b in buttonPressed method

Comment: define your button in the header file....... @property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *b;

Comment: doesn't work. I am doing something in the method buttonPressed and then I want to change that button Image. Your line of code just says to write that statement in the cellForRow method.

Comment: ya but you should define your button in your header file... see my last comment

Comment: already did..but I want those changes when I press the button...after the buttonPressed method.

Comment: run the code and check... b.png image appears only when the button is clicked and changes back to a.png when the press is released, or do you want the image b.png to remain even after the button is released?

Comment: image should remain after the button is released